# двумерный ndarray разваливается на list одномерных ndarray при присвоении его значения элементу другого list

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

**Python 2.7.12 (x64)**
**Используемые возле проблемы библиотеки:** PyBrain, SciPy

---

**Контекст проблемы:** необходимо получить из PyBrain результат, передаваемый через переменную типа list, содержание которой изменяется при обращении к функции, результатом является двумерный ndarray.

**Задача:** необходимо построить list из нескольких двумерных ndarray разных размеров.

**Сама проблема:** в указанную переменную типа list записывается не двумерный ndarray, а list из одномерных ndarray.

**Частично удачные попытки решения:** попытка избавления от внешнего list по средствам scipy.array() и scipy.vstack() дает вполне удовлетворительный результат, но только на отдельной переменной - при попытки присвоить элементу того list'а значение этой переменной она разваливается на list из одномерных ndarray.
Кто может подсказать как обойти эту проблему?

---

Я к сожалению все никак не могу повторить эту проблему в "тепличных" условиях, но попытки поиска проблемы выглядят так:

```
out=[]
self.layer[i]._forwardImplementation(self.inputs[i],out)
print 'out =\n',out,type(out)
out=vstack(out)
print 'out =\n',out,type(out)
self.outputs[i][:]=array(out.T)
print 'self.outputs[i] =\n',self.outputs[i],type(self.outputs[i])
```

А вывод этого:

```
out =
[array([ 0.,  0.,  1.,  1.]), array([ 0.,  1.,  0.,  1.])] <type 'list'>
out =
[[ 0.  0.  1.  1.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.  1.]] <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
self.outputs[i] =
[array([ 0.,  0.]), array([ 0.,  1.]), array([ 1.,  0.]), array([ 1.,  1.])] <ty
pe 'list'>
```

Comment: приведите пожалуйста примеры ваших входных и ожидаемых данных

Comment: Впервые пользуюсь stackoverflow.com, все непонятно как и сама проблема. Обычно хватало документации, интернета и небольшого шаманства, а тут тупик...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо всем заглянувшим, проблема неожиданно найдена в исходном коде:

```
self.outputs[i][:]=array(out.T)
```

А вот ошибка ----**^** - присвоение значения не элементу list'а, а его содержимому, т.к. изначально это был list пустых list'ов.
Так что для воспроизведения проблемы подойдет следующий код:

```
>>> from scipy import array
>>> lst=[[], [], []]
>>> a=array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
>>> a
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
>>> lst
[[], [], []]
>>> lst[1][:]=a
>>> lst
[[], [array([1, 2, 3]),array([4, 5, 6])], []]
```